# Apply versioning to the list forms

Tags: versioning

Each list in SharePoint comes with default forms and view pages such as `DispForm.aspx`, `NewForm.aspx`, `EditForm.aspx`, `AllItems.aspx`.

As far as I know versioning can be applied to list items.

So my question is can we apply versioning to these pages also as I also have some custom pages for some of the views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The List Forms are stored in special subfolders of lists and libraries that are not subject to version control. So, it's not possible to apply versioning for the list/library forms.

Comment: Please feel free to mark it as answer, if it has helped you because it might help someone in future too :)